# Append JSON data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON data from my server like,

> [    {
>         "list_of_query": [
>            12,
>            13,
>            15,
>            1
>         ],
>         "queries": [
>            {
>               "query_count": 12
>            },
>            {
>               "list_of_query": []
>            }
>         ]    } ]

This is working fine, when i need to update the JSON value, like

> [    {
>         "list_of_query": [
>            12,
>            13,
>            15,
>            1
>         ],
>         "list_of_query2":{"query1":1,"query2":2},
>         "queries": [
>            {
>               "query_count": 12
>            },
>            {
>               "list_of_query": []
>            }
>         ]    } ]

I tried something like push operation,

> query_details = {DATA_FROM_SERVER};
>   query_details.push({"list_of_query2":{"query1":1}});

But, when i try this it's appending data with initial node. like,

> [    {
>         "list_of_query": [
>            12,
>            13,
>            15,
>            1
>         ],
>         "queries": [
>            {
>               "query_count": 12
>            },
>            {
>               "list_of_query": []
>            }
>         ]    },    {"list_of_query2":{"query1":1}} ]

How to resolve this?

Comment: `query_details[0]["list_of_query2"] = {"query1":1};`

Comment: Oh Thanks Robby Cornelissen, I got a solution now. It's working fine. :)